# How to print another page with a button using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wonder how to print another page without need to go the certain page that I need to print with a button.

I have a page called Receipts I already have Print button in it. On click to the print I want to print another page called `Print.php` which is there.

Here is my Ajax code:

```
        // Update bill status and print
        $(document).on('click', '.update_status', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var ordernum=$(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({  
                url:"pages/UpdateBillStatus.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{ordernum:ordernum},
                success:function(data){
                    document.getElementById('status'+ordernum).innerHTML = data;

                    // This is the part that I wrote but it still open the Print.php page then print
                    var printWindow = window.open('http://localhost/LaLigaCafe/pages/Print.php?ordernum='+ordernum+'');
                    printWindow.print();
                }
            }); 
        });
```

So what I need is printing the page without need to going there just printing in my current page.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Afaik you cannot print a page without displaying it first. The only thing that comes close is to call `window.print()` then `window.close()` from inside the document after it was loaded; this will load the document and immediately show the print dialog, then close the window/tab right after the print job has left the browser. (also note that ajax is completely irrelevant here)

Comment: First thanks for your comment. I already knew about that but when I put `window.close()` the result on print is blank page I don't know what is the problem when I put the `window.close()`. As for your note; this ajax for updating the bill status to "paid" so after updating the bill status: Print the bill.

Comment: Yes, I get what the point of the ajax call is, but it is unrelated to the printing issue you're asking about. Anyway, all you need to do is add `<script>window.print(); window.close();</script>` to the end of `print.php`, then simply call the window.open() command to load it.

Comment: Yesss. you absolutely right bro, but when I'm adding `<script>window.print(); window.close();</script>` its open the `print.php` and close immediately.

Comment: Weird. Comment out `window.close()`. What happens now?

Comment: The page closing immediately without printing ,but I forgot to mention that I'm going to the `print.php` using a `href` tag is that making difference?

Comment: Let me rephrase: if you *just call* `window.print()`, what happens? Is the command ignored? Did you remove `printWindow.print();`?

Comment: In ajax: `window.open(self.href);` for going to the `print.php`
In `print.php` page: `<script>window.print(); window.close();</script>`
The result is opening the page very fast and page closing again and command ignored.

Comment: Bro thanks so much. It's working now with `setTimeout` function

Comment: Did you put the commands at the end of the document? Right before `</body>`? You shouldn't need a timeout then.

Comment: Yes I did. I already put it there exactly